# Printing out all the subsets of a set

Tags: java, performance

1. I am concerned about creating too many objects in my code.
2. Am I using duplicate code? Can I cut down on the number of lines of code?

Note: I only want to use recursion to solve this. Any suggestions on the design of the program and naming convention used here are appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Subsets {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> superSet = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        superSet.add(1);
        superSet.add(2);
        superSet.add(3);
        superSet.add(4);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists = Subsets.getSubsets(superSet);
        System.out.println("final set ==> " + lists);
    }

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getSubsets(ArrayList<Integer> SubList) {
        if (SubList.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = addToList(SubList.remove(0),
                    SubList);
            return list;
        } else {
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
            list.add(SubList);
            return list;
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> addToList(
            Integer firstElement, ArrayList<Integer> SubList) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfLists = getSubsets(SubList);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> superList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (ArrayList<Integer> iList : listOfLists) {
            superList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(iList));
            iList.add(firstElement);
            superList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(iList));
        }
        return superList;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may try and operate on the original list's `.toArray()`: this way you will have no need to create sublists of your original list

Answer (score 2):

You can combine your two methods in just one method, making the whole process much easier to understand due to less "jumping around".

```
static <T> List<List<T>> getSublists(List<T> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        // if empty, return just that empty list
        return Collections.singletonList(list);
    } else {
        List<List<T>> sublists = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        T first = list.get(0);
        // for each sublist starting at second element...
        for (List<T> sublist : getSublists(list.subList(1, list.size()))) {
            //... add that sublist with and without the first element
            // (two lines more, but this preserves the original order)
            List<T> sublistWithFirst= new ArrayList<T>();
            sublistWithFirst.add(first);
            sublistWithFirst.addAll(sublist);
            sublists.add(sublist);
            sublists.add(sublistWithFirst);
        }
        return sublists;
    }
}
```

Some more points:

- I'd recommend using the more generic `List` whenever possible.
- Also, no need to restrict the method to lists of integers.
- That code definitely deserves some comments.
- You are actually returning sub-*lists*; name your methods accordingly.
- Note that by calling `remove` on the input list, you are *modifying* the original list!

Answer (score 1):

My only input is about the `getSubsets()` method. I'd change it to:

```
   static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getSubsets(ArrayList<Integer> SubList) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list; //You're gonna make a list either way.
        if (SubList.size() > 0) {
            list = addToList(SubList.remove(0), SubList);
        } else {
            list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
            list.add(SubList);
        }
        return list;//You only need one return statement
    }
```

I generally don't like multiple return statements, because each one represents a path through which your method can just end abruptly, even if there's more code. But this **is** something up for debate (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement)).

You also make a list object in both cases, so why not just make it upfront and make things more readable?

Also, I would douse that code in comments. And finally, I'd probably just make my own class instead of dealing with that horrible syntax.

This saves you from typos, too:

```
class ArrayListHolder extends ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>{
      //This can be an inner class.   
}

  //For example, your addToList method will look like:

private static ArrayListHolder addToList(
         Integer firstElement, ArrayList<Integer> SubList) {
    ArrayListHolder listOfLists = getSubsets(SubList);
    ArrayListHolder superList = new ArrayListHolder();
    for (ArrayList<Integer> iList : listOfLists) {
        superList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(iList));
        iList.add(firstElement);
        superList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(iList));
    }
    return superList;
}
```

That's just purely my opinion on what you should do. No real reason other than readability, and my hatred for the `ArrayList` syntax. Otherwise, good job.